# How can I can do better with my R code to analyze word counts

Tags: performance, r

I am new to R and to learn I start to code to do things that interest me. I have a biological background and I am very interested in bioinformatics.
I know some python, but I want to use R as tool to apply some statistical analysis, once R is build in that thinking.

K-mer are substrings/words counted in a slide window (in my case of length 1, it means they overlap). Example:

```
AGCATTGGGACAT
AGC
 GCA
  CAT
   ATT
    TTG
     TGG
      GGG
       GGA
        GAC
         ACA
          CAT
```

The we count each ord ou kmer.
I count kmers/**words**/**n-grams** of **length (k)** 1-10 in some genomes and my goal is to find under/over represented kmers in this genomes.
I write some R code, but seems to me it is not very efficient. It takes to long to read the csv files, select the necessary data and to the stats.

Hope some of you guys would have with some ideias or tips to the code do better.

I compare the counts with the expected values, obtained by a High Markov Order, than calculate the variance, standard deviation, the z-scores, etc...
Then I selected the words by a e-value (alfa) with 0.01. For 4^6 (4096 possible words) I get more or less 200 words.

This is a example of input:

```
A   167981
C   77361
G   77560
T   167983
AA  65544
AC  18941
AG  28260
AT  55235
CA  23043
CC  18508
CG  7602
CT  28208
GA  23256
GC  16484
GG  18645
GT  19175
TA  56138
TC  23428
TG  23053
TT  65364
AAA 27001
AAC 8762
AAG 10349
...
```

This is a example of out put:

```
kmer    observed    expected    observed_freq   Zscore  Pval    Eval    rank
AAAAAA  1139    1376.16784735997    0.00232029905171272 -9.99779788296386   1.55823528020429e-23    6.38253170771679e-20    1
GAAAAT  338 494.315292339662    0.000688552308585514    -9.05021175302625   1.42691358118129e-19    5.84463802851856e-16    2
TTTTTT  1188    1397.96314403911    0.00242011876508755 -8.80934951714221   1.2587414031676e-18 5.1558047873745e-15 3
TTTAAA  695 810.032973280273    0.00141581022031637 -6.64539757722037   3.0239968595903e-11 1.23862911368819e-07    4
AACTCC  65  103.301775147929    0.000132413905497214    -6.05507022362132   1.40356421623009e-09    5.74899902967844e-06    5
...
```

I think the code works right, but it is slow.

So I really appreciate any tip to improve it.

Thank you by your attention and time.

Paulo.

```
        select_data <- function(counts, k){
        df_obs <- subset(counts, nchar(kmer) == k)
        return(df_obs)
    }

expected_high_markov_var <- function(kmer, counts){
    kmer_exp <- numeric(0)
    n <- nchar(kmer)
    pref <- substr(kmer, 1, n - 1)
    p <- as.double(counts[which(counts$kmer == pref), 'observed'])
    suf <- substr(kmer, 2, n)
    s <- as.double(counts[which(counts$kmer == suf), 'observed'])
    mid <- substr(kmer, 2, n - 1)
    m <- as.double(counts[which(counts$kmer == mid), 'observed'])
    exp <- (p * s) / m
    kmer_exp <- exp
    kmer_var <- exp * (m - p) * (m - s) / (m^2)
    return(list(kmer = kmer, expected = kmer_exp, variance = kmer_var))
}


generate_all_kmers <- function (k, 
                                seq = '', 
                                alphabet = c('A', 'C', 'G', 'T')) {
    kmers_list <- seq
    for (i in 1:k) {
        kmers_list <- unlist(lapply(kmers_list, function (kmer) {
        paste0(kmer, alphabet)
    }))
  }
  kmers_list
}


get_kmer_expected_var <- function(counts, kmer_list, k){
    df <- select_data(counts, k)
    n <- length(kmer_list)
    expected <- data.frame(kmer = character(), expected = numeric(0), variance = numeric(0))
    for(i in 1:n){
        exp_var <- expected_high_markov_var(kmer_list[i], counts)
        expected[i, ] <- exp_var
  }
    merged_df <- merge(df, expected, by = "kmer")
    return(merged_df)
}


kmer_frequency <- function(df, k, col){
    new_name <- paste(col, "_", "freq", sep = "", collapse = "")
    num_rows <- nrow(df)
    total <- sum(df[, col]) + k -1
    for(i in 1:num_rows){
        freq <- df[i, col] / total
        df[i, "frequency"] <- freq
  }
    names(df)[names(df) == "frequency"] <- new_name
    return(df)
}

get_kmer_sd <- function(kmer_list, kmer_data){
    n <- nrow(kmer_data)
    for(i in 1:n){
        var <- kmer_data[which(kmer_data$kmer == kmer_list[i]), "variance"]
        sd <- sqrt(var)
        kmer_data[i, "sd"] <- sd
  }
    return(kmer_data)
}

get_kmer_Zscores <- function(kmer_list, kmer_data){
  n <- nrow(kmer_data)
  for(i in 1:n){
    obs <-  kmer_data[which(kmer_data$kmer == kmer_list[i]), "observed"]
    exp <-  kmer_data[which(kmer_data$kmer == kmer_list[i]), "expected"]
    sd <-  kmer_data[which(kmer_data$kmer == kmer_list[i]), "sd"]
    zscr <- (obs - exp) / sd
    kmer_data[i, "Zscore"] <- zscr
  }
  return(kmer_data)
}

pval <- function(kmer_list, kmer_data){
    n <- nrow(kmer_data)
    for(i in 1:n){
        zsc <- kmer_data[which(kmer_data$kmer == kmer_list[i]), "Zscore"]
        pval <- pnorm(-abs(zsc)) * 2
        kmer_data[i, "Pval"] <- pval
  }
    return(kmer_data)
}


get_e_vals <- function(kmer_list, kmer_data){
    n <- nrow(kmer_data)
    for(i in 1:n){
        pval <- kmer_data[which(kmer_data$kmer == kmer_list[i]), "Pval"]
        eval <- n * pval
        kmer_data[i, "Eval"] <- eval
  }
    return(kmer_data)
}

# get the exceptional words by a thresholder e-value
exceptional_kmers <- function(kmer_data, eval=0.05){
  exceptional_kmers <- kmer_data[which(kmer_data$Eval < eval), ]
  exceptional_kmers <- exceptional_kmers[order(exceptional_kmers$Zscore), ]
  exceptional_kmers$rank <- rank(exceptional_kmers$Zscore)
  return(exceptional_kmers)
}


analyse_kmer_data <- function(filenames, 
                              kmer_list, 
                              k,
                              output_data){
  colunm_to_keep <- c("kmer", "observed", "expected", 
                      "observed_freq", "Zscore",
                      "Pval", "Eval", "rank")
  for(filename in filenames) {
    name <- basename(filename)
    message("Calculating the statistics from file: ", name)
    final_name <- paste0(substr(name, 1, 15), "_kmer", k, ".csv")
    oligos <- read.csv(filename, 
                       header = FALSE, 
                       col.names=c("kmer", "observed"))
    df <- get_kmer_expected_var(oligos, kmer_list, k)
    rm(oligos)
    df <- kmer_frequency(df, k, "observed")
    df <- get_kmer_sd(kmer_list, df)
    df <- get_kmer_Zscores(kmer_list, df)
    df <- pval(kmer_list, df)
    df <- get_e_vals(kmer_list, df)
    df <- exceptional_kmers(df, eval = 0.001)
    final_data <- subset(df, select = colunm_to_keep)
    out <- file.path(output_data, final_name)
    write.csv(final_data, file = out, row.names = FALSE)
    rm(df)
  }
}
```

kmer_list it is all possible kmer of length k, eg., the genome alphabet is {A,C,G,T}, so if I want all kmers of length (k) = 2, my list will be the all possible 4^2 (4^k) combinations of the letters of the alphabet, in this case = 16:
AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT.

Comment: I would avoid "rolling your own" versions of these types of programs.  Most of what you are trying to do is available with the BioConductor project for R (https://www.bioconductor.org/install/).  For example, you can easily obtain counts of DNA k-mers in given DNA sequence with the `countDnaKmers` in the BioConductor `setTools` pakage. The k-mers are searched in a set of search windows, which are defined by start and width parameter.  For example:

`dna_sequence<-"AGCATTGGGACAT"
countDnaKmers(dna_sequence, 3, 1:3, 3)`

returns:

`AGC 1 0 0
ATT 0 0 1
CAG 0 0 0
CAT 0 1 1`

etc.

Comment: @3209Cigs but I got your point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What is `kmer_list` ? what is `k`? we can not test the code...

But, that said, I adjusted 3 functions, without testing them, maybe they give some speedup:

```
expected_high_markov_var <- function(kmer, counts){
  kmer_exp <- numeric(0)
  n <- nchar(kmer)
  pref <- substr(kmer, 1, n - 1)
  counts2 <- as.double(counts$observed)
  p <- counts2[which(counts$kmer == pref)]
  suf <- substr(kmer, 2, n)
  s <- counts2[which(counts$kmer == suf)]
  mid <- substr(kmer, 2, n - 1)
  m <- counts2[which(counts$kmer == mid)]
  exp <- (p * s) / m
  kmer_exp <- exp
  kmer_var <- exp * (m - p) * (m - s) / (m^2)
  return(list(kmer = kmer, expected = kmer_exp, variance = kmer_var))
}


kmer_frequency <- function(df, k, col){
  new_name <- paste(col, "_", "freq", sep = "", collapse = "")
  num_rows <- nrow(df)
  total <- sum(df[, col]) + k -1
  rez <- sapply(1:num_rows, function(i) df[[col]][i] / total)
  df[, "frequency"] <- rez
  names(df)[names(df) == "frequency"] <- new_name
  return(df)
}

get_kmer_sd <- function(kmer_list, kmer_data){
  n <- nrow(kmer_data)
  rez <- sapply(1:n, function(i)
    sqrt(kmer_data$variance[kmer_data$kmer == kmer_list[i]]))
  kmer_data[, "sd"] <- rez
  return(kmer_data)
}
```

p.s. there are probably a lot more that could be rewritten...

Comment: Hi there, hope now it gets more clear. Thanks

Comment: Ordinarily we take answer invalidation quite seriously, but it seems your answer was written before the question was clear enough for a proper review. The question is much clarified by the edits, so can I ask you to modify the answer instead?

Comment: @ Mast I am sorry about the missing information. Some times I write as if the subject is know for everyone and that is not true. I will try to give more detailed information in future questions. Thank you.